# Python search files with multiple extensions

Tags: python

I wish to search a directory, and all contained subdirectories, for files with a substring contained within their name and one of three possible extensions

Please can you help me edit the following code

```
os.chdir(directory)
files = glob.glob("**/*{}*.pro".format(myStr), recursive = True)
```

I wish to find files with the extension .pro, .bd3 and .mysql

I'm running Python 3.5

Comment: If you're trying to do something with `glob` and it's too complicated for you to understand how to write the glob, it's time to switch to using `os.walk` and filter manually.

Comment: search for the 3 separately, store in 3 separate lists, and then combine the lists? that would probably triple your runtime, are you searching through a large directory?

Comment: Yes, there's numerous subdirectories and many levels. Plus I'm searching for around 7000 different files already. Tripling the time is really not an option

Answer (score 0):

You could create a list and loop over it

```
exten_to_find = ['.pro','bd3','.mysql']
```

you could format like this for iteration

```
files = glob.glob("**/*{x}*.{y}".format(x = myStr, y = extension_toFind), recursive = True)
```

Comment: See the comments on the original question.  This would search the directories 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

you could try:

```
def get_files_with_extension(my_str, exts):
    for f in glob.iglob("**/*{}*.*".format(my_str), recursive = True):
        if any(f.endswith(ext) for ext in exts):
            yield f
```

Answer (score 0):

Actual-glob syntax has no way to do this. The "enhanced glob" syntaxes of most modern shells can, but I'm pretty sure Python's `glob` module is only very lightly enhanced.

Under the covers, `glob` is a pretty simple module, and [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) link to the source. As you can see, it ultimately defers to `fnmatch`, which is also a pretty simple module, and while ultimately just builds a regex and defers to that. And of course you can do alternations in a regex.

So, one option is to fork all the code from `glob.py` and `fnmatch.py` so you can build a fancier pattern to pass down to `re`.

But the simplest thing to do is just stop using `glob` here. It's the wrong tool for the job. Just use [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) and filter things yourself.

If you understand how to write a regex like `r'.*{}.*\.(pro|md3|mysql)'.format(myStr)`, use that to filter; if not, just write what you do know how to do; the performance cost will probably be minimal, and you'll be able to extend and maintain it yourself.

```
files = []
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('.'):
    for file in filenames:
        fname, fext = os.path.splitext(file)
        if fext in {'pro', 'md3', 'mysql'} and myStr in fname:
            files.append(os.path.join(root, file))
```

If it turns out that doing a set method and a string method really is so much slower than regex that it makes a difference, and you can't write the regex yourself, come back and ask a new question. (I wouldn't count on the one I used above, if you can't figure out how to debug it.)

Also, if you're using Python before… I think 3.5… `os.walk` may actually be inherently slower than `iglob`. In that case, you'll want to look for `betterwalk` on PyPI, the module that the current implementation is based on.

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a try